# Download file size is different than the server size

Tags: php, file, ubuntu, size

I downloaded an MP3 file from my server, but the downloaded file size is different that the server size:

[image]

The file size on the server is:

```
ls -l alfirdaous.com_AhmadAlObaid_HafsAnAssim_001.mp3 
-rw-r--r-- 1 alfirdaouscom alfirdaouscom 419036 Mar 24  2014 alfirdaous.com_AhmadAlObaid_HafsAnAssim_001.mp3

du -sh alfirdaous.com_AhmadAlObaid_HafsAnAssim_001.mp3 
412K    alfirdaous.com_AhmadAlObaid_HafsAnAssim_001.mp3
```

I am wondering this is happening with many files from my server, people are complaining about this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have some file compressing system on your server

Comment: @ShivSingh You could not possibly know that.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen yes you are correct because can be many reason to not show correct files size on server. but i suggest to check file compression and disk quota system.

Comment: Well, the file cannot be played as well

Comment: you can find some good information on your issue here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62049/why-are-text-files-4kb and here http://superuser.com/questions/66825/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk